# Finding Eligibility of a country from given data using python

Tags: python, database, data-science

**The question which im trying to solve is as follows:**

Which country has the biggest difference between their summer gold medal counts and winter gold medal counts relative to their total gold medal count?

Only include countries that have won at least 1 gold in both summer and winter.
This function should return a single string value

**Data**

Gold: Count of summer gold medals

Gold.1: Count of winter gold medals

Gold.2: Total Gold

**Code**

```
def answer_three():    
    df1=df[(df['Gold']>0) & (df['Gold.1']>0)]    
    df['difference']=(df1['Gold']-df1['Gold.1']).abs()/df1['Gold.2']    
    return df['difference'].idxmax()    
answer_three()
```

**Error**

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-cf807e29ca1b> in <module>()
      3     df['difference']=(df1['Gold']-df1['Gold.1']).abs()/df1['Gold.2']
      4     return df['difference'].idxmax()
----> 5 answer_three()
      6 

<ipython-input-7-cf807e29ca1b> in answer_three()
      1 def answer_three():
----> 2     df1=df[(df['Gold']>=1) & (df['Gold.1']>=1)]
      3     df['difference']=(df1['Gold']-df1['Gold.1']).abs()/df1['Gold.2']
      4     return df['difference'].idxmax()
      5 answer_three()

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

*I am able to derive an answer without the condition that the country should have atleast 1 gold medal in both summer and winter. I am hoping someone could help me with fixing the error in line 2*

Thanks

Comment: Well, `df` isn't defined anywhere in your code before you use it in `answer_three()`.

Comment: can u let us see the df? and try 'global df' in first line of function. maybe that can be the problem.

Comment: the error literally tells you that `df` isnt defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define `def` as a `dict()`, the `NameError` exception occur when a variable is not instantiated. Try this:

```
def answer_three():
    df = {}
    df1=df[(df['Gold']>0) & (df['Gold.1']>0)]
    ....
```

Comment: This just exchanges `NameError` for `KeyError: 'Gold'`. The syntax is for a `pandas` DataFrame (hence the name `df` which is the standard name used for them). This answer does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
def answer_three():
    filterinfDataframe = df[(df['Gold'] > 0) & (df['Gold.1'] > 0) ]
    b = (filterinfDataframe['Gold']+filterinfDataframe['Gold.1']+filterinfDataframe['Gold.2'])
    a = (filterinfDataframe['Gold'] - filterinfDataframe['Gold.1'])/b
return filterinfDataframe.loc[a.idxmax()]
```

answer_three()

Comment: Please give a little more context to your answer and don't just post code.